# ComboBox SelectedItem does not change after clearing the observable collection

Tags: wpf, combobox, observablecollection, selecteditem, selectedindex

I'm having an issue with a `ComboBox` which is bound to an `ObservableCollection` and I was wondering if anyone can point to what I am missing.

I have a `ComboBox` which is bound to a simple `ObservableCollection<string>`.  Also I bind the `SelectedIndex` in a `OneWay` binding to some property.

In my application I get to a point where I want to clear the collection and repopulate it with different data and setting the `SelectedIndex` to a new value. for some reason the `SelectedIndex` binding does not work.

I'm attaching a little repro of the problem:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int j;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        Tables = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Tables { get; set; }

    private int _TheIndex;
    public int TheIndex
    {
        get { return _TheIndex; }
        set
        {
            _TheIndex = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TheIndex"));
            }
        }
    }

    private void aaaa(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        j = (j + 1)%10;
        Tables.Clear();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
        {
            Tables.Add(i.ToString());
        }
        TheIndex = j;
    }
}
```

the xaml is :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <ComboBox x:Name="TablesCombobox"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Tables}"
                      SelectedIndex="{Binding TheIndex, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <Button Content="asdasd" Click="aaaa"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Any reason why you don't just set TablesCombobox.SelectedIndex in aaaa() instead of TheIndex?  Not sure why the binding isn't working.

Comment: I just copy/pasted your repro code into VS2010 Express Beta 2 - and it works without a hitch...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is entirely caused by the `Tables.Clear()` line in your `aaaa()` method. Since `Tables` is an observable collection, wiping out all of the contents of the collection causes WPF to update the display with a new, empty list.  Then it tries to select the currently active item using `SelectedIndex`, which does not exist (because the list is now empty).  As a result, the binding engine is left with a value that cannot be applied, and decides to deactivate and detach the binding logic:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: Got PropertyChanged event from Window1 for TheIndex
System.Windows.Data Warning: GetValue at level 0 from Window1 using DependencyProperty(TheIndex): '1'
System.Windows.Data Warning: TransferValue - got raw value '1'
System.Windows.Data Warning: TransferValue - using final value '1'
System.Windows.Data Warning: Deactivate
System.Windows.Data Warning: Replace item at level 0 with {NullDataItem}
System.Windows.Data Warning: Detach
```

By the time it gets to the 'TheIndex = j;' line, the binding is no longer active and does not see the change to TheIndex, which means that desired index is no longer selected.

There are a couple of solutions to solve this:

1. **Don't blow away the entire collection every time.**  Without clearing the collection, the data binding logic always has an index to select, meaning it never detaches.
2. **Use a `TwoWay` binding.**  This works because now the ComboBox participates in binding; you clear `Tables`, the binding tries to set but can't find the index so the ComboBox resets to the special 'no index' position of -1, which then writes back to `TheIndex` (the two-way part), which is a valid value so the binding logic doesn't detach.
3. **Select no index (-1) before clearing the collection.** If no index (-1) is selected when `Tables` is cleared, then ComboBox doesn't try to apply `SelectedItem`, which means it doesn't 'see' the collection emptied and re-filled, and therefore, doesn't detach.

   ```
   private void aaaa(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       TheIndex = -1;
       j = (j + 1)%10;
       Tables.Clear();
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       {
           Tables.Add(i.ToString());
       }
       TheIndex = j;
   }
   ```

For performance, architectural, and clarity reasons, I'd highly recommend option 1, though I realize that your actual scenario may be more complex and require something along the lines of 3.

---

**Sidenote:**

Locating the reason behind binding issues like this is reasonably easy when using binding traces like the one posted above.  Turn them on for a single binding by declaring the System.Diagnostics namespace and adding `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High`to the binding that is causing trouble:

```
<Window xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase" />
...
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=x, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" />
```

More ways of debugging WPF bindings are [here](http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=52).

Answer (score 0):

I Know this is an old question but I have just experienced this problem myself so have written a helper method based on option 1 of @Nicholas Armstrong 's answer and thought I would share it, hope somebody will find it useful:

```
public void refreshDropdownOptions(ObservableCollection<object> OldOptions, ObservableCollection<object> NewOptions)
{
    MainWindow application = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;

    int highestCount = 0;

    if(OldOptions.Count() > NewOptions.Count())
    {
        highestCount = OldOptions.Count();
    }
    else
    {
        highestCount = NewOptions.Count();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < highestCount; i++)
    {   
        if(i < OldOptions.Count() && i < NewOptions.Count())
        {// If we have not exceeded the count of either list, copy the new value over the old
            application.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => OldOptions[i] = NewOptions[i]));                   
        }
        else if (i < OldOptions.Count() && i >= NewOptions.Count())
        {// If we have no more new options remove the old option
            application.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => OldOptions.RemoveAt(i)));
            highestCount = OldOptions.Count();
            i--;
        }
        else if (i >= OldOptions.Count() && i < NewOptions.Count())
        {// if we have no more old options to replace, add the new option to the end of the collection
            application.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => OldOptions.Add(NewOptions[i])));
        }
    }
}
```